# redirected page overrides real page in google search

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-search

I have 2 sites... a good-one and bad-one.
I wrote a program and stuck it on the good site.

Then I put (just as a javacript test) `window.location="good-one"` on the bad-one.

I found out what I needed to know and didn't bother removing the redirect (who cares?).

But now in google searches instead of my good site coming up... the bad one shows in the searches and then if you click of course you get redirected to the good one.

So I put the whole URL of the good site into google search (just to see what would happen) and the number on spot is the bad one.
The good site is not even in google index anymore. The bad one took over.

Does a redirection page have priority over the actual page?

Is this supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Using window.location isn't a way to change results in google. You have to use HTTP headers instead. Set the 301 HTTP header on the server side.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

example in PHP

```
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header ('Location: good-one');
```

Comment: The redirect was only a test... I didn't want to change results in google, it just happened and now if I delete the "bad" page the redirect goes with it and there will be no way to get to the good page and there will be nothing at all in google search for my "good" page.